# taxonomy listing per author

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy

I have to list taxonomy terms passing a uid argument. actually basic setup is 
I have image nodes which is associated with a birds vocabulary. so each image node can have a term from birds vocabulary attached. what I want to do is list all the terms which have the image nodes authored by user.
my approach was to create a taxonomy view and passing it a uid argument, but views doesn't have support for uid argument in taxonomy view. is there a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a 'Node' view instead, you can setup fields for the Taxonomy Terms attached to nodes then pass in a UID as an argument.